# Proving $\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{f(x)}{\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}+(x-\frac{1}{\epsilon})^2}\,dx=\pi f(\frac{1}{\epsilon})+O(\epsilon).$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory, asymptotics, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to prove that for a smooth function $f\in C^\infty$ which decays suitably fast, we have
$$\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{f(x)}{\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}+(x-\frac{1}{\epsilon})^2}\,dx=\pi f(\frac{1}{\epsilon})+O(\epsilon).$$

Start of proof:

We use that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{a}{a^2+x^2}\,dx=\pi$ for $a>0$.

This gives us

\begin{align}\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{f(x)}{\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}+(x-\frac{1}{\epsilon})^2}\,dx&=\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{f(\frac{1}{\epsilon})}{\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}+(x-\frac{1}{\epsilon})^2}\,dx+\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{(f(x)-f(\frac{1}{\epsilon}))}{\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}+(x-\frac{1}{\epsilon})^2}\,dx\\
&=\pi f(\frac{1}{\epsilon})+\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{(f(x)-f(\frac{1}{\epsilon}))}{\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}+(x-\frac{1}{\epsilon})^2}\,dx.\end{align}

So the rest of the proof is to show that $$\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{(f(x)-f(\frac{1}{\epsilon}))}{\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}+(x-\frac{1}{\epsilon})^2}\,dx$$ is $O(\epsilon)$ as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+$.

Equivalently, following the hint given by @J.C., the statement is equivalent to proving that $$\int\frac{f(x)-f(\frac{1}{\epsilon})}{1+(1-x\epsilon)^2}\,dx=O(1).$$

To see this, we divide the real line into a set where $x\sim\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ and a set where $x\not\sim\frac{1}{\epsilon}$.

On the set $|x-\frac{1}{\epsilon}|\leq\frac{1}{2\epsilon}$ the fact that $f\in C^\infty$ and the assumption that $f$ decays sufficiently fast allows us to Taylor expand around $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$. We *assumee*  $$f(x)=f(\frac{1}{\epsilon})+(x-\frac{1}{\epsilon})O(\epsilon)^2$$ for $x\sim \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ is valid. Then
$$\Bigg|\int_{\{|x-\frac{1}{\epsilon}|\leq\frac{1}{2\epsilon}\}}\frac{f(x)-f(\frac{1}{\epsilon})}{1+(1-x\epsilon)^2}\,dx\Bigg|=\Bigg|\int_{\{|x-\frac{1}{\epsilon}|\leq\frac{1}{2\epsilon}\}}\frac{(x-\frac{1}{\epsilon})O(\epsilon)^2}{1+(1-x\epsilon)^2}\,dx\Bigg|\leq\frac{1}{\epsilon}\frac{\frac{1}{2\epsilon}O(\epsilon^2)}{1}=O(1)$$ using the crude estimate $|\int_I f(x)\,dx|\leq |I|\sup_{x\in I}|f(x)|$.

On the set $|x-\frac{1}{\epsilon}|>\frac{1}{2\epsilon}$ we use that $f$ is uniformly bounded:
\begin{align}\Bigg|\int_{\{|x-\frac{1}{\epsilon}|>\frac{1}{2\epsilon}\}}\frac{f(x)-f(\frac{1}{\epsilon})}{1+(1-x\epsilon)^2}\,dx\Bigg|&\leq 2\|f\|_{L^\infty}\int_{\{|x-\frac{1}{\epsilon}|>\frac{1}{2\epsilon}\}}\frac{1}{1+(1-x\epsilon)^2}\,dx\\
&=2\|f\|_{L^\infty}\int_{\{|y|>\frac{1}{2}\}}\frac{1}{1+y^2}\,\frac{dy}{\epsilon}\end{align} where we made the change of variables $y=\epsilon x-1$. This means I can only show that $$\int\frac{f(x)-f(\frac{1}{\epsilon})}{1+(1-x\epsilon)^2}\,dx=O(\frac{1}{\epsilon}).$$

Comment: Equivalently, $\int\frac{f(x)-f(1/\epsilon)}{1+(1-x\epsilon)^2}dx\in O(1)$. Are your definite integrals $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$? Do we have $\epsilon\to0$, or $\epsilon\to0^+$?

Comment: @J.G. Yes, they are all $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ and $\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+$. I will make the changes in the question

Comment: If $f$ decays quickly enough, can't you just use dominated convergence on $\int \frac{f(x)-f(1/\epsilon)}{1+(1-x\epsilon)^2}dx$ to show that it converges to $\int f(x)dx?$

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed is the integrand dominated by an integral function?

Comment: I think you're right. If $|f(x)|\leq \frac{C}{|x|}$, then $|\frac{f(x)-f(1/\epsilon)}{1+(1-x\epsilon)^2}|\leq  |f(x)|+\frac{C\epsilon}{1+(1-x\epsilon)^2}$ which is integrable because $f\in L^1$ and $\int\frac{C\epsilon}{1+(1-x\epsilon)^2}\,dx=C\epsilon\int\frac{1}{1+y^2}\,\frac{dy}{\epsilon}=\int\frac{1}{1+y^2}\,{dy}<\infty$.